# Why changes to a windows service configuration is not persisted before/after reboot

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I tried to make `sensu-client` to have a dependency on the RPCSS. It is because if `sensu-client` starts too early, it cannot connect to the target `rabbitmq` server. It is probably because the network service is not ready yet.

I ran this command

```
sc config sensu-client depend= RPCSS
```

I double checked to make sure the dependency appears in the service dialog box.

[image]

Then I proceed to restart the server.

When the server is up again, the job is not running. The dependency also disappeared.

What happened?

Comment: Anything in event viewer?